# Distribution of balls of different types after drawing without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, combinations

Suppose I have an urn with $n$ balls. There are $t$ different types of balls (say, of different colors, or with distinct numbers printed on them), each representing a share $p_i (1 \leq i \leq t)$ of the total number of balls; thus, $p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_t = 1$.

I proceed to draw $b$ balls, without replacement, from the urn. Let $c_i (1 \leq i \leq t)$ be the number of balls of type $i$; thus, $c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_t = b$.

Which distribution represents the random variables $c_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, T$? How are the parameters of the distribution determined from $n$, $t$, the set $P = \{ p_1, \ldots, p_t \}$ and $b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: Thank you very much. Just did some Monte Carlo simulations and the multivariate hypergeometric distribution matches the results within the expected error.